# Getting full version numbers for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Is there a way to get the full version numbers of internet explorer, i.e. the version numbers you see when you open the about window?

Comment: Why do you need that?  What's wrong with `navigator.userAgent`?

Comment: I found this: http://www.pinlady.net/PluginDetect/IE/, maybe it can help.

Comment: There is a bug related to the spell-checker which crashes internet explorer, it's fixed in a particular update, so I wanted to check if the version is higher than that number.

Comment: Thanks Rocket, already seen that, unfortunately clientCaps does not work for ie11, which is where the problem is.

Comment: What bug are you referring to?  There must be a way to check for this bug *without* looking at the version number.

Comment: It's a bug that has to do with auto-correct on text fields if you run in 32-bit mode (default mode). It's mostly an issue if you have a large table with lots of cells. After a few edits in the cells, ie11 will crash. It has been fixed in a recent update. However to prevent this crash from happening in our web app, I would like to check if the true version is high enough and warn the user if it is not.

Answer (score -1):

The IE11 user agent string reports the version of the browser with a revision ("rv") token.

```
var isIE11 = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0") != -1);
```

I personally tested this over jsfiddle with IE11 and this code works

More details of the IE user agents here in MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know what version of ie11 is running, above code only tells if it is ie11 or not, I already know that.